# Performing -nt/-ot test in a POSIX sh

Tags: files, timestamps, posix, test

The built-in `test` and `[` utilities have the `-nt` ("newer than") and `-ot` ("older than") tests in most shells, even when the shell is running in "POSIX mode" (also true for the external utilities of the same names on the systems that I have access to).  These tests are for comparing modification timestamps on two files. Their documented semantics are slightly varying across implementations (with regards to what happens if one or the other file exists on not), but they are not included in [the POSIX spec. for the `test` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/test.html).

> They were not carried forward into the `test` utility when the conditional command was removed from the [KornShell] shell because they have not been included in the `test` utility built into historical implementations of the `sh` utility.

Assuming I'd like to compare the modification timestamp between files in a `/bin/sh` shell script and then take action depending on whether one file is newer than the other, as in

```
if [ "$sigfile"     -nt "$timestamp" ] ||
   [ "$sigfile.tmp" -nt "$timestamp" ]
then
    return
fi
```

... what other utility could I use, apart from `make` (which would make the rest of the script unwieldy to say the least)? Or should I just assume that nobody is ever going to run the script on a "historical implementation of `sh`", or resign to writing for a *specific* shell like `bash`?

Comment: As you can see in my answer, bash does not implement the `-nt` feature of `test` in a way that is expected since approx. 1995. You should use the `find` basd expression even with `bash` if you like correct behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

POSIXLY:

```
f1=/path/to/file_1
f2=/path/to/file_2

if [ -n "$(find -L "$f1" -prune -newer "$f2")" ]; then
    printf '%s is newer than %s\n' "$f1" "$f2"
fi
```

Using absolute path to files prevent a false positive with filename contains newlines only.

In case of using relative path, then change `find` command to:

```
find -L "$f1" -prune -newer "$f2" -exec echo . \;
```

Comment: technically, I think it fails if `$f1` only contains newlines ;)

Comment: @ilkkachu could be worked around with `-exec echo x \;` or similar?

Comment: @muru, yeah. `-printf` would be easy if it were standard

Comment: The overall esthetic impression of the test is horrible, but I presume that it would work... I would need to test and think. Would you not be able to work with the exit status of `find`?

Comment: @Kusalananda AFAICT, `find`'s exit status is independent of what the individual tests of `find` return - except perhaps if there's an error in actually running those tests. `find` exits 0 even if no files are found.

Comment: Yes, in this case `find` will indicate success whether it finds a matching file or not.

Comment: @ilkkachu ah right, fixed

Comment: You'd need the `-L` option for it to be equivalent to `[ -nt`.

Comment: Note that there's still a problem for filenames starting with `-` or `!`, `(`, `)`...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, but I insist `/path/to/file`, it should be absolute filename, no?

Comment: Note that the behaviour of `[ / -nt /nofile ]` varies with the implementation (but never outputs any error).

Comment: @cuonglm, hmm, if `$f1` is an absolute pathname, then the output will have at least the slash, and I don't think the `echo` is really required either. (Right?) Probably better to document the limitations in the answer, though.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes right, fixed

Answer (score 7):

This could be a case for using one of the oldest Unix command, `ls`.

```
x=$(ls -tdL -- "$a" "$b")
[ "$x" = "$a
$b" ]
```

The result is true if a is newer than b.

Comment: That doesn't work if file names start with `-` (missing `--`). You'd need `-L` for it to be equivalent to `-nt`. That doesn't work to compare `x` and `$'x\nx'` for instance.

Comment: Eek! But also huh.

Answer (score 5):

You raised an interesting question and made a claim that should first be verified.

I checked the behavior of:

```
$shell -c '[ Makefile -nt SCCS/s.Makefile ] && echo newer'
```

with various shells. Here are the results:

- **bash** Does not work - prints nothing.
- **bosh** **works**
- **dash** Does not work - prints nothing.
- **ksh88** Does not work - prints nothing.
- **ksh93** **works**
- **mksh** Does not work - prints nothing.
- **posh** prints: posh: [: -nt: unexpected operator/operand
- **yash** **works**
- **zsh** **works in newer versions**, older versions print nothing

So four of nine shells support the **-nt** feature and implement it correctly. Correctly in this case means: **is able to compare time stamps on recent platforms that support sub-second time stamp granularity**. Note that the files I selected differ typically only a few microseconds in their time stamps.

Since it is easier to find a working `find` implementation, I recommend to replace

```
if [ "$file1" -nt "$file2" ] ; then
    echo newer
fi
```

by a `find` based expression.

```
if [ "$( find "$file1" -newer "$file2" )" ]; then
    echo newer
fi
```

works at least as long as `$file1` does not only contain newlines.

```
if [ "$( find -L "$file1" -newer "$file2" -exec echo newer \; )" ]; then
    echo newer
fi
```

is a bit slower but works correctly.

BTW: **Regarding make** I cannot speak for all make implementations, but `SunPro Make` supports time comparison with nanosecond granularity since approx. 20 years, while `smake` and `gmake` added this feature recently.

Comment: Is it a typical behavior of stackexchange to get downvotes for correct answers?

Comment: Are the "not working" tests not working because of a failure to compare sub-second timestamps (definitely?), or something else? What's the actual timestamps on the files involved in your test? +1 for the testing!

Comment: "Not working" means exactly what I wrote already: it does not print **newer** even though the left file is a few microseconds newer than the right one.

Comment: I think the downvote is probably about the confrontational wording. Here, it would be fairer to call it a limitation (significant in some contexts). Some `find` implementations like busybox or heirloom-toolchest will have the same limitation.

Comment: Well, it seems that you frequently use a similar wording without getting downvotes. BTW: The heirloom toolchest is unmaintained since many years and the only programs inside that are worth being mentioned are the enhanced `mailx` program and the enhanced `troff`.

Comment: You'd need `-L` for the the `find` version to  be equivalent to `-nt`. It would also fail on file names that start with `-` or `!`, `(`...

Comment: @schily don't mind about the downvote, it often happen randomly. /me +1

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do often get downvotes when I use a confrontational wording. Here it would help if you stated the context (files modified within same timestamp when truncated to second resolution) at  the start of the answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas schily Sorry guys, but where is confrontational wording in the answer, it looks great for me.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: good point: the only way to use files like `-foo` in the `find` command is to specify `find ./-foo`

Comment: @schily, yes, BSDs `find` have `find -f "$file"` for that but it's not portable.

Comment: Well `find` implementations seem to evolve. In September 2004, when I wrote `sfind` and `libfind`, other find implementations did not manage to handle arbitrary path name length and hard linked directories. So this was the main reason for writing `sfind`. The `libfind` project was started since there was working code ;-)

Comment: Hmm, the question asks about how to implement the "newer than" test with POSIX tools, given that it's not a part of POSIX sh. With that in mind, I'm not sure how the foray to the behavior in different shells is related, let alone why it should be the main point of an answer...

Comment: @ilkkachu Well, it connects with _should I just assume that nobody is ever going to run the script on a "historical implementation of `sh`"_. It's a useful comparison and shows that most shells do implement this test, but that they may fail on sub-second comparisons.

Comment: Did you use single square brackets in your bash test on purpose in order to cause a failure?  The rules and operators inside of [[]] and [] are different.  [[]] was used to allow bash some latitude in an alternate test implementation.  AFAIK, the '-nt' operator only works with double-square brackets.  If you are going to test bash's '-nt' feature, you might use the double brackets.